# Проверить число на соответствие маске

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть трехзначное число в string - "123", оно может быть указано с помощю маски - "XXX", маска соотвестственно охватывает не только "123" а и все трехзначные в даном случае числа. Маска может быть задана и с помощю чисел, например так - 
"1XX" где она указывает на все трехзначные числа с "1" на 0 позиции (100 - 199) или к примеру так - X1X где она указывает на все трехзначные числа с "1" на позиции 0 (010, 011, 012 ... 110, 111, 112 ... 210, 111 ...).
Как проверить что число (не только трехзначное) соответсвует маске?
У меня особенно трудно с вариантом X1X так как здесь два X.Я разделяю строку на substring (все комбинации) и проверяю состоит ли каждый substring только из "X" таким образом получаю позиции и длину всех подстрок с "X" внутри строки зная исходное число:
например "123" и маску "XXX" мне нужно лишь проверить вхождение числа в 0 - 999,
другой пример: "123" и маска "XX3" я знаю что у меня на 0 позиции 2 X т.е мне нужно сравнить 12 с 0-99 и 3 с 3, а вот
"123" и "X1X" - я знаю что X на 0 позиции длиной в 1 (0 - 9) и X на 2 позиции тоже длиной в 1. Мне нужно сравнить 2 с 1 в даном случае)

Comment: Что-то не пойму проблему... X - это же одна цифра? ну так просто идите и сравнивайте цифры, где они и в маске, и в числе; где в маске X - считайте проверку в этом разряде пройденной...

Comment: А при чём тут python?

Comment: На слове "строкизная" я "ламаюсь".

Comment: Может, вам нужны регулярки? Шаблоны типа `1\d\d`, `\d1\d`.

Comment: @nick_gabpe Это уникальный вопрос, по C#, C++ и python одновременно

Comment: @demonplus да, потому что мне более важен алгоритм, а не язык

Comment: @MikeWaters Русский язык точно не важен :)

Comment: @demonplus я не русскоязычный, мой вопрос поняли и я рад этому. 
я не вижу смысла в ваших комментариях, язык программирования мне не важен, если я делаю орфографические ошибки, то исправьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Превратите вашу маску в регулярное выражение, заменив в маске каждый `X` на `\d` и и дальше проверяйте используя регулярные выражения.